# Using Hex with SByte for Negative Values

Tags: .net, vb.net, hex

I'm trying to define an enum with an SByte data type (for binary-interop with some accompanying firmware). I have something like below:

```
Public Enum Codes AS SByte
   IDLE = &H0
   IN_PROGRESS = &H1
   DONE = &H2

   SOME_ERROR = &H80
   SOME_OTHER_ERROR = &H81
End Enum
```

Unfortunately the two error codes result in a compile time error: "Constant expression not representable in type 'SByte'."

Obviously it is attempting to treat these values as integers first and then convert them to SByte. As an integer 0x80 = 128. Since the range for an SByte is [-128, 127], this value is too large for an SByte.

If I use -(&H80) this is resolved. However, this doesn't work for -&H81 since this translates into -(129) instead of -127....

I could just use the decimal representations of these numbers to get around this, but I'd prefer to use hexadecimal (even with VBs horrible prefix) as this is consistent with the underlying assembly code.

So... if anyone knows the proper syntax for negative SByte values using hexadecimal I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter code such as:

```
Dim sb as SByte = -127
```

the assigned value is referred to as an integer (Int32) literal.  If you what to use the hexadecimal literal notation to produce an equivalent value, you must use the hexadecimal value for -127.

```
Dim sb as SByte = &HFFFFFF81 ' = -127
```

You can shorten it a bit, if you instruct the compiler to read the hexadecimal value a short integer (Int16) by appending the type suffix character "S"

```
Dim sb as SByte = &HFF81S ' = -127
```

As an aide in determining the hexadecimal notation for a value, you can use the VB `Hex` function in VS's "immediate window" to determine the characters to enter.

i.e.: `?Hex(-127)

will yield:  "FFFFFF81"